# Calculating probabilities from logit parameters estimated with effect coding

Tags: regression, probability

I calculated this multinomial logit model using an effect coding (-1 0 1). The variable edu3 is the education level (3 categories), sex has of course 2 categories and eduM3 is the education of the mother in 3 categories.

```
Parameter edu3 Estimate Pr*>*ChiSq

Intercept 0 -1.6882 <.0001
Intercept 1 -0.2962 <.0001
sex 0 0 0.0797 <.0001
sex 0 1 0.1304 <.0001
eduM3 0 0 1.8393 <.0001
eduM3 0 1 0.6276 <.0001
eduM3 1 0 -0.5476 <.0001
eduM3 1 1 0.3453 <.0001
```

From this, I would like to compute the resulting probabilities for every possible case, for example, the probability for a man (sex=0) whose mother has a education level 0 (edum3=0) to get an education level 0 (edu3=0).

The cross table for sex=0 gives this:

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
\hline
eduM3 & \text{edu3=0} & \text{edu3=1} & \text{edu3=2} \\
\hline
0& 32.36& 41.17& 26.46\\
1& 5.56& 51.08& 43.36\\
2& 4.38& 24.93& 70.7\\
\end{array}
$$

In this example, the wanted probability should then be 0.3236. However, when I implement parameters in the formula, I get this:

$$
\frac{e^{(-1.6882+0.0797+1.8393)}}{(1+e^{(-1.6882+0.0797+1.8393)}+e^{(-0.2962+0.1304+-0.5476)})} = 0.4581
$$

Why? I guess that something is wrong with my formula. It probably has something to do with the fact that I used an effect coding rather than a dummy coding.

Comment: Demographer, what are the table headers for the 2nd table?  What are the zeros, ones, and twos?

Comment: Sorry, it looked good in the text editor.The header is 0/1/2, being the categories of edu3. The first column is categories of edum3 (0/1/2).

Comment: Thanks, and I gather from your output that the base category for the multinomial logit is -1, since it only shows 0s and 1s for values of edu3, right?  What package are you using, by the way, is it R? I ask because I'm unfamiliar with the way the results are output. In Stata, the parameters for each equation are shown separately (e.g. the model of edu3=0 vs. edu3=-1 are all shown together, separated by a line break, and then edu3=1 vs. edu3=-1 are shown together)

Comment: I use SAS. Yes, the base category is -1 (for sex=1 and eduM3=2). The first column is the name of the independent variable. The second is the category of this variables. The third is the category of the dependent variable (ref=2). The fourth are parameters and the last are the p value.